# MySQL left join with 'b's limit

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, limit

First of all, i'm sorry to my wrong english.

I have one question for mysql query join with b.limit
show below two table

**Table 1 : Members**

> id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   user_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
>  
>   ...

**Table 2 : Members_opt**

> id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   members_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
>   category varchar(10) NOT NULL
>   ...

and one user have multiple columns of Members_opt.
and Members.id = Members_opt.members_id.

I want make this query

> SELECT * FROM Members a, Members_opt b WHERE a.id = b.members_id;

But this query makes below result.

```
id | user_name | category
01 | John  | cat
01 | John  | dog
01 | John  | bird
02 | olion | cat
03 | jenny | dog
```

I want if result have same id value, just add "limit 0,1" to category
so i want this result.

```
01 | John  | cat
02 | olion | cat
03 | jenny | dog
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The `JOIN` operation presents all possible combinations of rows in the two tables. So, if John has a dog, cat, and bird, and you do an ordinary JOIN, you'll get three rows for John.

(`SELECT .. FROM a,b WHERE a.something=b.something` is a `JOIN`. It uses old-fashioned syntax but is still a `JOIN`).

To meet your requirement, you need a way to get a virtual table (a subquery) containing just one pet per member.

```
               SELECT members_id, 
                      MAX(category) category
                 FROM Members_opt
                GROUP BY members_id
```

will do that. It selects the category (pet) with the name coming last in the alphabet. It returns at most one row per value of members_id.

Then you JOIN that virtual table (subquery) to your other table.

```
  SELECT a.id, a.user_name, b.category
    FROM Members a
    JOIN (
               SELECT members_id, 
                      MAX(category) category
                 FROM Members_opt
                GROUP BY members_id
         ) b ON a.id = b.members_id
```

This will return one row for each member showing the chosen category. If a member has no categories (no pets) this query will suppress that member's row. If you want your query to show members having no pets, use LEFT JOIN.

**Notice** that this query

```
 SELECT *    /* incorrect: nonstandard, unpredictable */ 
   FROM Members a, Members_opt b 
  WHERE a.id = b.members_id
  GROUP BY a.id
```

misuses a nonstandard extension to MySQL's implementation of `GROUP BY`. It won't work in newer versions of MySQL, but rather will get an error. It will, if it does work at all, return unpredictable results.  Read this.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Returning unpredictable results is worse than returning random results. When you misuse this `GROUP BY` hack in MySQL, each subsequent use of the query returns the same results, until it doesn't.